# Vstack alongside if function to remove any blanks from multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to utilise vstack but to cut out any blanks before I pivot.  I cannot find anywhere the function can be overlapped.  I have no requirement for the data to have a hierarchy across the order of responses.

So from the following I have used a basic vstack formula which feeds into the pivot but would love some help to remove the blanks before it will then feed directly into said pivot and/or graph.

=VSTACK(A3:A27,B3:B27,C3:C27)

[Initial data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OHfr.png)

[Sample of vstack output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r11qw.png)

[Pivot - including but including the blanks from the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSqfR.png)

Comment: Use `TOCOL()` instead.

Comment: Just for fun to mimic the pivot: `=LET(X,TOCOL(A3:C27,1),Y,UNIQUE(X),VSTACK({"Responses","Count of Responses"},HSTACK(Y,BYROW(Y,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(X=a))))),HSTACK("Grand Total",ROWS(X))))`

Comment: @JvdV While you were commenting, I was posting answer.

Comment: @Harun24hr, yup. I voted for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `VSTACK()`, instead use `TOCOL()` function with option ignoring blank cells. Try-

```
=TOCOL(A2:C50000,1)
```

Here `[ignore]` parameter `1` indicates `Ignore Blanks`.

And you can achieve you end result by following formula-

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(A2:C50000,1),t,UNIQUE(x),y,BYROW(t,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(x=a)))),CHOOSE({1,2},t,y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of a late response, but I had a similar issue myself and found the perfect article: [https://www.xelplus.com/excel-vstack-function/[][1]](https://www.xelplus.com/excel-vstack-function/%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

Basically you just wrap the Vstack in the Filter function, and set the second argument to "is not blank". The second argument in the function also just takes the first column, not sure if it can take other columns as well but this worked for me to remove all blank rows

i.e., from the article, =FILTER(VSTACK('R10-1:R40-3'!A2:G50), VSTACK('R10-1:R40-3'!A2:A50) <> "")

Or, I used mine in a table, so with table nomenclature:
=FILTER(VSTACK(CostsandComm_Table[[EmployeeId 1]:[Memo 1]],
VSTACK(CostsandComm_Table[[EmployeeId 1]:[EmployeeId]] <> "")